# Is there any way to exclude a context in the ContextConfiguration when JUnit testing?

Tags: java, spring, junit4, spring-annotations, applicationcontext

So the thing is I want to load a set of application contexts that follow the regular expression that is anything follow by -context.xml, ok?

This saves me a lot of time since I don't need to add a lot of application contexts one by one.
Now, one of those application context is giving me trouble and I want it to not be included in the context configuration. Can I add something to the **@ContextConfiguration** annotation that removes a particular application context from the previous locations?

Is not a big nuisance, but I'm curious...
Here's some code if this helps you:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
            "classpath*:resources/*-context.xml"
            })
    public class Tests{
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context exclusion is not possible in Spring. You can declare which contexts to use by using [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.1-test-context-profiles). In each test you can select which profile will be used, so in turn which beans will be loaded to context.